# Processing tiles generated by gdal2tiles.py in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I used gdal2tiles.py to split a large image into 256x256 tiles.
I then used leaflet to visualize this large image. This image is georeferenced and appears rotated on the screen. Everything is fine.

I'd like to process the 256x256 tiles of my image before there are displayed. 
It is possible to watch load event to have opportunity to process tile but the tiles we get in load event are not in my image space. There are vertically aligned tiles in map, and my image is rotated.

Is there a plugin to handle this case ?

There is one to get coordinates in image space from a point clicked on map, but knowing which image tiles are hitting a map tile requires more than an inverse transform.

Comment: This is unclear. What kind of processing do you want to apply to the tile images?

Comment: Any processing that takes a tile as input and return an image with same size as the input tile ( edge detection, color conversion, ...).
For an example with Open Sea Dragon, see https://codepen.io/iangilman/pen/JbpPqq, where simulated processing is coloring in red. But I need geolocalisation.